# html—top and bottom property with dynamic size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, user-experience

I have a div I'm trying to give specific properties to. My page has a header and a footer, and I want the body to consist of a panel with 15px padding all around, but the bottom padding always ends up variable. If the window is too tall, I end up with bottom padding that's 3–4x larger than the top and side padding, and if the window is too small, the footer overlaps the bottom of the panel. My html essentially looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                Title
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried giving #content the following style:

```
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
bottom: 15px
```

hoping that I could get a constant border all around, but when I have both top and bottom properties, top just overrides bottom and I still have that variable padding on the bottom. Any ideas?

For further clarification, see jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b005bqpp). Notice that when you drag the divider above Result, the lower border moves up or down at about half the speed you're moving your cursor—I want to make it so the bottom of the panel stays a constant distance from the bottom of the window.

Thanks!

Comment: could you reproduce this in a fiddle? but it sounds like it *could* be an issue with the use of a fixed position.

Comment: Can you add your html and css so we can what you have tried?  Its hard to determine your issue with the given code and explanation.

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle before, so I'm not too sure how to load the proper resources, but I'll post a stripped-down version of the html above.

Comment: So I totally wasn't helping myself by not figuring out how to import bootstrap into jsfiddle. Added a link above to demonstrate the issue I'm having. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to just introduce a wrapper to avoid stomping on Bootstrap styles.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
.my-wrapper{padding:15px;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0t60qp4/)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make a difference for me. It's not so much that I need 15px padding as much as I need both the top and bottom of the panel to stay a constant distance from the top and bottom of the browser window, no matter how big the browser window is.

Comment: You should add a JSFiddle with your code so we can better understand the problem.